# Solving what pay rate someone has

Tags: word-problem

Someone makes $\$2,000$ per week for working $50$ hrs per week. $40$ of those hours are at regular pay and $10$ hrs are at overtime pay of $1.5\%$ additional pay. What is the employee's rate of pay?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that overtime pay is $1.5\%$ of regular pay. Maybe $150\%$. Or $1.5$ times regular pay.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that overtime pay rate is $1.5\%$ extra than the normal pay rate. Suppose $x$ is the employees rate of pay. Then we have that $40x+10(1.015x)=2000$. So $50.15x=2000$, so that $x=\frac{2000}{50.15}\approx 39.88$.